# Perl Split the CPU Load Output

Tags: regex, perl, split

Uptime Command output is:

```
6:00am  up 55 day(s), 17:18,  1 user,  load average: 0.29, 0.29, 0.28
```

I need first `0.29` only. How can I split or remove rest character?
Also plz tell me how do you guyz make regex. I don't want to visit this site again and again. I want to learn. 
Thanks

Comment: if you want to learn regex you should start from regexone. Its a good site

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place where skilled programmers can ask for help from their peers with coding problems that they can't resolve themselves. It *isn't* a place to ask for a tutorial on ideas that you have never met before. If you show what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work for you then people will help you. If you have no idea even how to start then your question should be deleted

Answer (score 2):

Using `split`

```
my ($num) = split ', ', (split ': ', $string)[1];
```

Or a regex

```
my $num = $string =~ m/: ([^,]*)/ ? $1 : undef;
```

Comment: thanks. I used regex. I hope one day I will learn this regex thing. Because my entire process is based on strings. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Miller: I understand you wanting to resolve Perl programming problems - it's why we love the language - but please take care of the Stack Overflow philosophy, which is ultimately to be able to mark every question as a duplicate of a precedent instead of writing custom answers to every request. And no, I often don't follow that advice myself, so this is as much a reminder to self as it is a comment to you

Comment: @Borodin *nod*  I appreciated this discussion on Meta SO recently: [`Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/1733163), especially this response: [`incentive for finding dups`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252196/1733163).  In this case, it's tough to decide if a proper search would find a dup though, and it definitely would take longer than the 30 seconds it takes to type an answer.  Either way, I agree with continuing to try to encourage quality over quantity with SO posts, especially with new comers.

Answer (score 0):

```
uptime | awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $14}'
```

i guess this will work

if you want only regex you can use this :

```
uptime | grep -o '[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]' | head -1
```

which will return only the first group of numbers after load average:

Answer (score 0):

using awk is one more way to achieve this.

$ cat info.txt

Uptime Command output is: 6:00am up 55 day(s), 17:18, 1 user, load average: 0.29, 0.29, 0.28

$ cat info.txt | awk -F 'load average: ' '{print $2}' | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'

0.29